# W3C Validation Errors with this Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm getting w3c validation errors with this Javascript code and wonder if a kind gent/lady would spare me a moment to take a gander.

```
// hide all element nodes within some parent element
function hideAll(parent) {
    var children = parent.childNodes, child;
    // loop all the parent's children
    for (var idx=0, len = children.length; idx<len; ++idx) { /* ERROR HERE */
        child = children.item(idx);
        // if element node (not comment- or textnode)
        if (child.nodeType===1) {
            // hide it
            child.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

**The Errors are:**

- element "len" undefined
- character ";" not allowed in attribute specification list

The semi-colon at `idx<len;` is where it goes wrong.

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong with the above code snippet?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
// hide all element nodes within some parent element
function hideAll(parent) {
    var children = parent.childNodes, child;
    // loop all the parent's children
    var len = children.length;
    for (var idx=0; idx<len; ++idx) { /* ERROR HERE */
        child = children.item(idx);
        // if element node (not comment- or textnode)
        if (child.nodeType===1) {
            // hide it
            child.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rick. However, I'm still getting the exact same validation errors.

Comment: Validation highlights the semi-colon here: **idx<len;**

Comment: I've moved it out of my HTML which fixes it. It was just in case it was a known issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
          **// hide all element nodes within some parent element



             function hideAll(parent) 
             {
                var children = parent.childNodes, child;

                // loop all the parent's children
                var len=children.length;

                 for (var idx=0; idx<len; ++idx) 
                 { /* ERROR HERE */

                   child = children.item(idx);

                    // if element node (not comment- or textnode)

                     if (child.nodeType===1) 
                     {
                         // hide it
                         child.style.display = 'none';
                     }
                } 
         }**
```